# trouble in scrolling in uitableview

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift, scroll, cell

I've created a Tableview populated with cells with a fixed `tableView.rowHeight = 95.0`

The problem is that when I add more cells and I try to scroll to the bottom, I can see only half cell at the bottom. I mean, when I try to scroll I can't scroll down so that to see the entire last cell added.

Seems the scrolling bar doesn't work well. Is this a bug of Xcode or did I make something wrong?

I don't want a resizable height cell but I want my cell fixed with with 95.0 but at the same time I want my scrollbar to work better.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is if the table height exceeds the your mainview. At that time srollview of tableview also goes down.solution is keep the tableview height within the bounds of mainview(i.e your viewcontroller's view)